# Why was this answer put into community wiki?

Tags: discussion, community-wiki

[Stalin cultivated a "Friend of the Children" image: Why? Did other communist/socialist leaders do the same?](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/10351/why-did-stalin-cultivate-friend-of-children-image/10353#10353)

Why was this answer put into community wiki? It is entirely mine - every word and all the research, with the exception of one minor language adjustment made by one other user, and an edit made by a another which I rolled back.

Subsequently I myself removed an entire segment, in response to a comment from the OP.

Comment: On the supposition that you don't want it CW, I've taken the liberty of converting it back to a normal answer. Feel free to edit it again and check the wiki box if you want it back. :-)

Comment: I removed a personal attack. Also, interestingly, it actually said in the edit history why it was made a community wiki. It doesn't any more, perhaps because it's no longer a community wiki.

Comment: @T.E.D. - thank you.

Comment: @Vector - The identity of other editors besides yourself was completely irrelevant to the question. We really should **take pains** to not to personalize our posts unless absolutely nessecary. It makes things emotional when they need not be. Also, the ensuing chaos creates lots of unnessecary work for your poor moderators.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the question [What are "Community Wiki" posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts) we find this exerpt:

> ### How does a post become a Community Wiki post?
>
> There are several ways a question or answer can enter community wiki
> mode, and most of these ways will occur automatically based on the
> rules of the system.
>
> Posts enter community wiki mode when one of the following happens:
>
> - The body of the post has been edited by at least five (**5**) different users.
> - The post has been edited ten (**10**) times by the original owner.
> - The **answer**'s author checks the *community wiki* checkbox when composing the answer. Note that this checkbox isn't available to new
>   users.
> - The **answer** is edited by its original author, who when doing so opts to check the *community wiki*.
> - An answer posted to a Community Wiki question will also be Community Wiki. Note that when a question is made CW after answers have already
>   been posted, the existing answers are not normally converted to CW
>   automatically.
> - The question generates more than **30** answers (**15** on Super User, **60** on Code Golf). In this case, the question and all answers
>   will enter community mode, as will any future answers.
> - A moderator has reason to believe that the **question** serves better in community wiki mode - if you believe your question [should
>   be
>   converted](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/08/the-future-of-community-wiki/)
>   to a Community Wiki, you may [flag it for moderator
>   attention](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/392/should-the-community-wiki-police-be-shut-down/7183#7183).
>
> ** note that the rules outlined above are based on observations; the
> actual behavior of SO is subject to change without notice, and may
> well have done so since this was last updated...*

A brief viewing of [the history](https://history.stackexchange.com/posts/10353/revisions) of your linked question shows that it was edited (as of my last viewing) 17 times by the original owner. So I'm guessing that's why.

Comment: Frankly, this wikification process idea always seemed to me like a Really Bad Idea for a variety of reasons. This is now even MORE idiotic since we have edit suggestions capability for low-rep users so there's absolutely no upside, no matter how miniscule.

Comment: @DVK - I have to admit that I find the "10 times by original owner" part a bit mystifying (as apparently did the OP). It almost seems like a tax on us poor spellers. :-(