# I didn't check community wiki - and no one has edited my answer- why is it a wiki?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, community-wiki

About a minute ago, I answered the question: [Is there a correlation between the colonial power and the stability/success of the post colonial state?](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/9783/is-there-a-correlation-between-the-colonial-power-and-the-stability-success-of-t)

My answer is listed as community wiki.  I didn't check the box, nor has it been edited.  None of the reasons listed at [Why was this answer put into community wiki?](https://history.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/774/why-was-this-answer-put-into-community-wiki) apply here.  Why is it in community wiki?  Did I make an erorr in posting my answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because the question has become a community wiki.

From the [What Are Community Wiki](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts)'s Post:

> An answer posted to a community wiki question will also be community
>   wiki.